# On Arduino Micro, is there a way to use the "Serial" port from pin connections?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

[Micro](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMicro?setlang=en) and Leonardo have two serial ports, denoted by "Serial" and "Serial1."
I can use Serial1 through the RX and TX pins for my sensor, a TF Mini, and still get output to the Arduino IDE through the Serial connection via USB.

I would like to, instead send that output via Bluetooth, which also requires a serial connection.  I have attempted [Software Serialization solutions](https://github.com/TFmini/TFmini-Arduino/blob/master/TFmini_Arduino_SoftwareSerial/TFmini_Arduino_SoftwareSerial.ino) for the sensor, without success.

Is it possible to access both Serial and Serial1 connections through the pins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Serial port in the Arduino Leonardo is virtual, so there is no physical way to interact with it, you'll need to do bit banging in other GPIO pins to simulate this connection. By doing this, it will slow down your sketch if you are doing more complicate stuff. And if you add an extra connection via Serial1 port, will be worse.